# I am trying to vertically center two divs using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to vertically center two divs with jQuery. I did a similar thing horizontally and it worked fine.

This is my javascript:

```
$j(function() {

    $j('#arrowright', '#arrowleft').css({
        'margin-bottom' : -$j('#arrowright').height()/2,
    });

});
```

My CSS:

```
#arrowright {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 50%;
    left:10px;
}
#arrowleft {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 50%;
    right:10px;
}
```

The html is:

```
<div style="position: relative">

    <div id="arrowright"></div>

    <div id="arrowleft"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hard to tell what's going without the html, you can update the question with the html

Comment: <div id="arrowright"><img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/slideshow-nav-prev.png" alt="arrowright" /></div><div id="arrowleft"><img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/slideshow-nav-next.png" alt="arrowleft" /></

Comment: Sorry let me be more clear

Comment: The containing div has position: relative and the divs are each holding an image

Comment: Update the question with your generated html mark up. The container markup should do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like below where, depending on the item, the bottom margin is adjusted accordingly (where the value should be entered as a string):

```
$('#arrowright, #arrowleft').css('margin-bottom', function() { return '-' + $(this).height() / 2 + 'px' } );
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sLvj2/1/

Comment: still no luck. When I inspect element it does not show the margin-bottom attribute at all